# How to display an empty value in NumericUpDown control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, numericupdown

I have a Windows Forms  application that includes `NumericUpDown` control With  `Minimum` and `Maximum` values set to (50:80) accordingly and step 1.

When form loads the `NumericUpDown` shows 50.

I know that `NumericUpDown` is for picking numbers and numeric types and always has a value, but is there any way to make it show empty when form loads?

Comment: are you just trying to avoid the change event when the form loads?  Numerics default to a value and not Empty or Nothing, also 'Empty', Null, Nothing violates the Min Max settings - if the user didnt touch it the value returned would be invalid.  So you are out of luck on all counts.  Perhaps of you told us WHAT you were trying to do...

Comment: Thanks Bjørn For Your Replay

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't make default NumericUpDown control empty. NumericUpDown need a value to increase/decrease from. If 'empty' is only a matter of look empty when user see the form at first, then you can hack it by setting NumericUpDown's Text to empty:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    NumericUpDown1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

With that NumericUpDown1 will look empty, but NumericUpDown1.Value is still 50.

Comment: (Note that the Text property is hidden in Intellisense (Visual Studio), but it's there).